# ¿Qué lema es este?

Tags: expresiones, modismos, diferencias-regionales, coloquialismos, dialectos

Estaba escuchando ["Andalucía nuestra" (sáb., 20 feb 2021)](https://www.canalsur.es/radio/programas/andalucia-nuestra/detalle/10890434.html). Al final de la entrevista, el alcalde de Algar (Cádiz) dice, "Y termino por un lema..." (35:48). Pero, no lo oí claramente. ¿Qué es lo que dijo? Sé que quiere que los oyentes vengan a visitar su pueblo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, el alcade —muy apurado apretando su mensaje al final de la extensa entrevisa— concluye con:

> *(...) y termino con un lema: deciros que **aquí ya tengo** las puertas abiertas  de par en par para todo el que nos quiera visitar*

(Para quien le suene raro, como a mi, el uso de **[lema](https://dle.rae.es/lema?m=form)** que hace el alcalde,  es correcto, en tanto resulta como una abreviación temática de su mensaje de invitación a conocer los atractivos de Algar).